Windows 11 provisioning package computer name doesn't match in computer management
I recently discovered provisioning packages and it is making my life a lot easier. As part of the package, it renames the machine to %SERIAL% and adds it to the domain.
As part of my checks after the load to make sure everything is good, I am checking to make sure the local admin account I specified in the package got created successfully.
When I go to System and Computer Name under Advanced system settings, it shows the computer name I want based on %SERIAL%.
But when I go to Computer Management to make sure the admin account was created, the local account shows as DESKTOP-AB123547\myuser (the AB123457 being random).  GpUpdate fails too. Something about the computer name.
So far to fix it I've had to remove it from the domain, and re-add it and that fixes it.
Is there maybe something I can run at the end of the provisioning package to fix this?

For anyone who runs into this, I guess I just needed to be more patient.  It seemed to sort itself out after a reboot.
